# Kentico and add Form that posts to external source

Tags: forms, kentico

I want to create a Salesforce Web to Case from on my Kentico Site.

I have a template built and am inheriting the from that.

I create a new page and then add my form code to the Page Tab > Source and Save.

When I load the page on my site, the form is displayed, but when I hit submit, the form does not do the post action.

How do I accomplish this?

TIA, Jason

Answer (score 0):

Since Kentico is built on web forms, each page's content is wrapped inside a form tag.

Adding your markup (including a form tag) in the middle of a Kentico page results in a nested form, which is invalid.

The quickest way to make this work is probably:

- Create a basic HTML document with your markup, and put it on a new page in  a "Custom Response" web part. https://www.screencast.com/t/PuwwnFTGGpAJ
- Then display that new document in an iframe on your current page.

If that won't work, you can put your form markup in a div hidden by CSS. Then use javascript to move the div to a location after the page's main form tag. You can then use CSS to absolutely position the form on the page.

I hope this is helpful, good luck.

Comment: This didn't work.  I put the custom response in the Template that I created the main Form Control of the ASP.NET took over and it just did a postback.

I am now going to just try to use jQuery and a Button .onClick.  Get the element values by ID and do a $.post that way.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution - nicely done!

RE: The custom response web part - the only thing I can think of is that the custom response only works in Kentico's "live" mode. If you were viewing the page in preview mode, the custom response wouldn't fire. If you ever try this approach again, check the page in a new browser where you're not logged into Kentico.